# Keeping some files private

Tags: php, private, html5-video

I was trying to create a directory of private files that could only be accessed when a user logs in. To do this, I used a folder outside the web directory, and then php to access it, if allowed.

Here's an example:

```
function display_movie($file){

printf("`<video id='movie' width='960' height='416' controls='controls' onerror='fix()'>`<br/>
`<source src='movie.php?file=%s' type='video/ogg; codecs=\"theora, vorbis\"'>
</video>", rawurlencode($file)`);

}
```

This works great for images, but breaks the media player.  Also, I've only tested this locally on a Linux machine.

Any ideas? Thanks.

This is in movie.php...

```
if(file_exists($fileDir . md5($file) . $ext)) {
  $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . md5($file) . $ext);
}

header('Content-type: video/ogg');
echo $contents;
```

Comment: please show the contents of movie.php

Comment: those <br/> html tags should not be in the php code

Comment: they werent....i was trying to display the post properly and failed. i deleted them though

Comment: First suggestion: Create a text file with something recognisable in it, and place it in the same directory you are putting the movies in. Adjust the `movie.php` file to not set the `Content-type`, and to just echo it straight through, and then access the movies.php file directly through the browser. This should prove whether you are having trouble accessing, reading and relaying contents from that folder. If you see the text, then it will be something to do with the handling of the video files in this manner. But it should clarify the situation at least a little.

Answer (score 0):

What is with the `<br />` in you're movie.php ?

Did you tryed to see if movie.php echoes the file contents ? ( view source on you're page , then copy the movie source src "movie.php?file=..." and paste it in you're browser , see if it get's the movie out ) .

Allso you need to move the header and echo inside the if statement , if that file doens't exist you can echo a different standard movie :

```
if(file_exists($fileDir . md5($file) . $ext)) {
  $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . md5($file) . $ext);
} else {
  $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . md5(MOVIE_NOT_FOUND));
}
header('Content-type: video/ogg');
echo $contents;
```

Where MOVIE_NOT_FOUND is a constant, movie you whant to display if the requested one is not found .

One other thing you could do is enter you're full uri to the movie php in you're source src ( like "http://localhost/some/uri/movie.php?file=..."

From where do you get $fileDir , $file and $ext in you're movie.php ?

---

Edit: should take care of the file_get_contents problem you have

```
$file = $fileDir . md5($file) . $ext;
header('Content-type: video/ogg');
//set aditional headers you may whant here
ob_clean();
flush();
if( file_exists($file) )
{
    readfile($file);
} else {
    readfile($fileDir . md5(MOVIE_NOT_FOUND));
}
exit;
```

Comment: It gets the contents, but the viewer breaks: scroll doesnt work and that sort of thing.  $fileDir is the path to the file, $file=is passed from auth.php and $ext='.ogv'

Also, if I dont get the file from a separate directory, but rather from the same directory, the player works fine. However, the ogg isnt hidden.

Comment: then you're problem is on the frontend ( client side , html/css/js/whatever ), not on the server if the server passes the movie .

Comment: A very small suggestion - compiling the `$fileDir . md5($file) . $ext` once, and storing it as a string variable, which is then used for the `file_exists()` and `file_get_contents()` functions would make this solution a little neater. Could even move the `header()` call to the top, and then, rather than use the `$content` variable to hold the result, just echo it straight through.

Comment: @Lucanos: you're right , however concidering his problem you can tell he's not realy experienced so it would be easyer for him to understand what's going by not changing his code too much , tough you're comment makes sense in a big way for example i would do it in a totaly different way so i can pass multiple types of videos and more strict tests to make shure everithing goes as planned

Comment: The problem is accessing the movie through file_get_contents() does not correctly grab the entire video file.

Comment: i've neaver heard or encountered this problem ( that file_get_contents() doesn't get all the content ) but you can try my second code and see if it works .